# How do I shift items in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Let's say that I have an array of strings like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

and I want to shift the elements of the array such that

1. The first element always remains fixed
2. Only the remaining elements get shifted like so ...
3. The last element in the array becomes the 2nd element and is shifted through the array with each pass.

Pass #1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
Pass #2: 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
Pass #3: 1, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Pass #4: 1, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has got to be homework.  This should have the homework tag on it.

Comment: Andy, asking about homework questions is generally okay.  See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Why do you say it has got to be homework? It's a very practical question.

Comment: @Josh Einstein-- Because it looks a lot like a homework problem or an interview question, in that it's a toy problem that shows basic concepts of array manipulation.

Comment: If you can change the data structure, a LinkedList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) might be a better choice.

Comment: Well @Kevin, @mmr he says it's not homework so either he's lying or the assumption was incorrect. I just don't know what kind of questions we expect from new users without questioning their motives.

Comment: @Josh Einstein-- I'm not saying that asking homework questions is bad.  On the contrary, I think he should definitely get an answer.  The idea is to just say that it's homework, though, rather than presenting it as a 'real' problem.  He doesn't say it's not homework...

Comment: @mmr He did say it wasn't homework in his response to Kevin. But anyhow, no harm done. He got some helpful answers.

Comment: If you don't provide enough good details, people on SO mock you. If you provide too much, TL;DR. If you provide exactly the amount of details required and word it clearly and concisely, people think it's "homework". *sigh*

Answer (score 7):

Because this looks like homework, I'm posting an unnecessary complex, but very hip LINQ solution:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

int[] result = array.Take(1)
                    .Concat(array.Reverse().Take(1))
                    .Concat(array.Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse())
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the fastest way to do this in C# is to use Array.Copy. I don't know much about pointers in C# so there's probably a way of doing it that's even faster and avoids the array bounds checks and such but the following should work. It makes several assumptions and doesn't check for errors but you can fix it up.

```
void Shift<T>(T[] array) {
    T last = array[array.Length-1];
    Array.Copy(array, 1, array, 2, array.Length-2);
    array[1]=last;
}
```

**EDIT**
Optionally, there is Buffer.BlockCopy which according to [this post](http://danielvl.blogspot.com/2004/04/use-bufferblockcopy-instead-of.html) performs fewer validations but internally copies the block the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Because this looks like homework, I'm not going to solve it for you, but I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Remember to not overwrite data if it isn't somewhere else already.  You're going to need a temporary variable.
2. Try traversing the array from the end to the beginning.  The problem is probably simpler that way, though it can be done from front-to-back.
3. Make sure your algorithm works for an arbitrary-length array, not just one that's of size 8, as your example gave.

Comment: @Andy - Can you provide the code of what you have already tried. It is easier for people to correct your code then write it from scratch. Also, shows that you have tried something and aren't just looking for the answer given to you.

Answer (score 0):

Although sounds like homework like others suggest, if changing to a List<>, you can get what you want with the following...

```
List<int> Nums2 = new List<int>();
for( int i = 1; i < 9; i++ )
   Nums2.Add(i);

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    Nums2.Insert( 1, Nums2[ Nums2.Count -1] );
    Nums2.RemoveAt(Nums2.Count -1);
}
```

Comment: A LinkedList will give significantly better performance on larger collections.

Comment: I agree... much simpler for linked list -- even double-linked for reversal capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Define this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enuml)
    {
        var count = enuml.Count();
        return enuml
            .Skip(count - 1)
            .Concat(enuml.Take(count - 1));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipAndRotate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enuml)
    {
        return enum
            .Take(1)
            .Concat(
                enuml.Skip(1).Rotate()
            );
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
var array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

var pass1 = array.SkipAndRotate().ToArray();
var pass2 = pass1.SkipAndRotate().ToArray();
var pass3 = pass2.SkipAndRotate().ToArray();
var pass4 = pass3.SkipAndRotate().ToArray();
```

There's some repeated code there that you might want to refactor. And of course, I haven't compiled this so caveat emptor!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Josh Einstein's but it will do it manually and will allow you to specify how many elements to preserve at the beginning.

```
static void ShiftArray<T>(T[] array, int elementsToPreserve)
{
    T temp = array[array.Length - 1];

    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > elementsToPreserve; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    array[elementsToPreserve] = temp;
}
```

Consumed:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
ShiftArray(array, 2);
```

First pass: 1 2 8 3 4 5 6 7